# Distinct layouts for distinct user types

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I have two distinct userTypes 'reader' and 'publisher'. This information is stored in Meteor.users document `Meteor.users.userType: 'publisher'` or it can `Meteor.users.userType:'reader'`

How can I dynamically add elements to the appBody depending on userType?

The data context and things like menu items will of course be different for userTypes

I have referenced https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-dynamic-template

HTML:

```
<head>
 <title>Site</title>
</head>

<template name="appBody"> //this is layoutTemplate
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
        <div class = "container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">menu title A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu title B</a></li>
                ***DYNAMICALLY ADD LIST ELEMENT DEPENDING ON WHICH 'userType' IS LOGGED IN HERE***
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{> UI.dynamic template=currentUser.userType }}
</template>


<template name="reader">
  unique layout
{{> yield}}
</template>


<template name="publisher">
  unique layout
{{> yield}}
</template>
```

router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'appBody',
    loadingTemplate: 'appLoading'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have in a way broke the app into a logged in state and not logged in state.
When the user does log in, depending on their userType, I either render a 'reader' template or a 'publisher' template. Both of these now behave as the layout templates for each user so to speak. Then I can yield in templates into these using iron:router.

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'parent',
loadingTemplate: 'appLoading'
});


<template name="parent">
  {{#if currentUser}}
  {{> UI.dynamic template=currentUser.userType }} //this returns 'reader' or 'publisher'
  {{else}}
  {{> notLoggedIn}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="notLoggedIn">
//unique styling for non logged in users such as join and log in.
{{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="reader">
//unique styling and custom reader navigation menu
{{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="publisher">
//unique styling and custom publisher navigation menu
{{> yield}}
</template>
```

Now I can render any template into the yield region from Router.route :))

```
Router.route('/path', function () {
this.render('templateName');
}
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for your support. Sometimes somebody else's method can spark another idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `UI.dynamic`, I suggest writing your own template selector function:

Paraphrasing https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-dynamic-template, it needs to look like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  UI.body.helpers({
   getTemplate: function () {
     return something;
   }
  });
}
```

I would suggest renaming the helper to userType and using as follows:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  UI.body.helpers({
    userType: function () {
     var user = Meteor.user();
     return (user && user.userType)? user.userType : ''; 
   }
  });
}
```

and using `{{> UI.dynamic template=userType }}`

You can change the '' in the `return` statement to 'anonymous' if it fails for users that are not logged in, but then you will also need to write an anonymous user type template.

However, you do not need UI.dynamic to achieve this:

You could use a meteor if template helper like this:

```
{{#if userTypeIs "publisher"}}
 {{ > publisher }}
{{/if}}
{{#if userTypeIs "reader"}}
 {{ > reader }}
{{/if}}
```

This won't work by itself.

Next, you need to include a helper function in JS for `Template.appbody.userTypeIs`

To do that locally, include them with `Template.appbody.helpers()`

```
Template.appbody.helpers({
    ....other helpers....
    userTypeIs: function(t){
          var user = Meteor.user();
          return ( (user) && (user.userType) && (user.userType === t) );
    }
```

`userTypeIs` might be useful for other templates, so if desired it could instead be defined globally for all templates using `Template.registerHelper()`:

```
Template.registerHelper('userTypeIs', function(t){
      var user = Meteor.user();
      return ( (user) && (user.userType) && (user.userType === t) );
 }
```

Notice that this function returns a Boolean, to be used with the if, and takes a parameter, which is quoted in the template.  The execution uses "defensive programming" in that it will return false if for some reason Meteor.user() or Meteor.user().userType is not defined.

This templating is standard in Meteor, no need to import any additional modules into a project for this particular task.

Also, all of this is in the [Meteor API docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/), which I encourage you to read in its entirety if you have not already done so.

Comment: This seems like it can work but it is a lot of checks. I have been banging my head trying to think of the solution and I think I have finally got it. Please take a look at my answer and let me know if you find any holes.
This Meteor docs is always open in one window to reference.

Comment: To invoke the templates for reader and publisher you need `{{ >reader }}` or `{{ > publisher }}` where I put the list item.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to do. Let me guess, `currentUser` is undefined in that context...

Comment: Paul, yes current user is defined in {{> UI.dynamic template=currentUser.userType }}